# Error al realizar geodificación inversa con Nominatim en jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, geocodificación

quiero obtener las direcciones de un conjunto de coordenadas que tengo en un .csv mediante geocodificación inversa, este es mi script:

```py
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoder import Nominatim
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ccarosanchez\Prueba_geocoding\Coordenadas.csv')
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ccarosanchezinei")
df_geo = pd.DataFrame()
df_geo['coordenadas'] = df.LAT + ',' + df.LON
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
reverse = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=1)
df_geo['Time'] = df_geo['coordenadas'].apply(reverse)
```

Mi script se interrumpe al ejecutar la última linea de arriba, este es el error que obtengo para todas las coordenadas del csv:

```py
RateLimiter caught an error, retrying (0/2 tries). Called with (*('-11.99664,-77.079795',), **{}).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /reverse?lat=-11.99664&lon=-77.079795&format=json&addressdetails=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)')))...
```

El error de arriba se repite para todas las coordenadas.
Alguna solución?

Comment: Si implementás [el ejemplo en la definición de RateLimiter de `geolocator.reverse`](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/extra/rate_limiter.py#L171), ¿funciona?

Comment: Hola, me sale el mismo error.